# Link two data types together in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I'm an absolutely beginner in Haskell.
I want to construct two data types like:

```
data A = A B
data B = B A
```

(With additional data in the objects of course)

I would like to create an object like that:

```
A (B this)
```

where this should be the `A`-object. `A` should contain a reference to `B` and `B` should container a reference to `A`.

How is it possible or is there another solution in functional-programming to link two data-objects together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in exactly the way you said:

```
recursiveA :: A
recursiveA = A recursiveB

recursiveB :: B
recursiveB = B recursiveA
```

Or, if you like it short,

```
recursiveA = fix $ A . B
```

But really, this is pretty useless. In a functional language, you do *not* want to think about references<sup>1</sup> to objects<sup>2</sup>. We talk about *values*, and a "reference" to a value is the same thing as the value itself, since we don't have mutablility to screw things up. You can't use refences like you would perhaps in Java.

The most obvious – and normally best – way to link two types together is put both of them in another `data`.

```
data AandB = AandB A B
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Well, there's also `IORef`, which gives you a mutable reference... but this is really a nasty real-world accomodation hack, not something you should use as a beginner.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>BTW, many of the more mathematically inclined Haskellers will mean *types* when the say "object": types are the objects of the [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_%28mathematics%29) **Hask**.</sub>

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, I will try out, if I can change my design in a functional style.

Comment: Of course, it's all the same, but may I suggest `this = A (B this)` as a variant that comes even closer to what the OP already discussed in the question?